# ElasticSearch on Alias not working

Tags: elasticsearch, alias

I have the following alias set up:

```
"items": {
    "aliases": {
        "items_0": {
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "accountid": "0"
                }
            },
            "index_routing": "0",
            "search_routing": "0"
        }
    }
}
```

When I search for a document in the items index with an accountid = 0, it gets returned. Yet when I search for a document using an index of items_0 it does not get returned. I am using the exact same search criteria, just changing the index name from items to items_0. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you didn't index your documents with the same `_routing` value as the one you specify in your alias.

For example, for these documents (where `_routing` is specified):

```
POST /items/test/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":1,"_routing":0}}
{"accountid": 0}
{"index":{"_id":2,"_routing":0}}
{"accountid": 0}
{"index":{"_id":3,"_routing":0}}
{"accountid": 5}
{"index":{"_id":4,"_routing":0}}
{"accountid": 3}
```

Running

```
GET /items_0/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "accountid": 0
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Returns the correct results. So, you need to make sure that your documents were indexed with the `_routing` id that you are using in the alias.

Comment: Thanks. I am specifying the route value when indexing. Is there a way to check the document has the correct route?

Comment: Yes: `GET /items/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "accountid": 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields": ["_routing"]
}`

Comment: Yes the document I am searching for was routed using the routing id. Not sure therefore why the document doesn't show when searching on the alias.

Comment: Can you post the complete commands you use for indexing, checking the routing value afterwards, alias, searching?

Comment: ok found problem, was adding alias as items _0 not items_0. sorry - thanks for pointing me in right direction - doing a items_0/_search gave me a {-

"error" : "IndexMissingException[[items_0] missing]",

"status" : 404
}